# What are the equivalent classes for KeyGesture and InputBinding in .Net Standard Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I am converting my .Net 4.6 class library to .Net Standard Library 1.4 (as we want to support Cross platform.

Couple of my classes and interfaces use KeyGesture and InputBinding classes. These classes belong to System.Windows.Input. But I can not find these classes in XAMARIN\PCL. What are the equivalent classes for those I can use? Or if no classes present, how can I replace the code with ?

I am using those classes to provide shortcuts to user interactions in UI. Ex - to cut some text, user can press **CTRL + X** I use KeyGesture class to achieve this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: those classes are fairly platform dependent so they probably don't make sense for a PCL.